# Prisma can't connect to SQL Server, getting generic error

Tags: node.js, sql-server, prisma

Following Prisma tutorial: https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/relational-databases-typescript-postgresql

`.env`:

```
DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://DESKTOP-8IHA17K\SQLEXPRESS:1433;database=PrismaDB;integratedSecurity=true;trustServerCertificate=true;"
```

`schema.prisma`:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlserver"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Post {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  title     String   @db.VarChar(255)
  content   String?
  published Boolean  @default(false)
  author    User     @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  Int
}

model Profile {
  id     Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  bio    String?
  user   User    @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId Int     @unique
}

model User {
  id      Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  email   String   @unique
  name    String?
  posts   Post[]
  profile Profile?
}
```

The database already exists and is empty.

When I try to run

```
npx prisma migrate dev --name init
```

I get this error:

```
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": SQL Server database
```

> Error: Schema engine error:
> Error creating a database connection.

The only difference from the tutorial is that I'm trying to use SQL Server, not PostgreSQL

No more detailed error, how can I get a more detailed error?

Answer (score 0):

I had to enable and start SQL Server Browser Service